# Suggestion-tags appear on click in input Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-taggit

Hello im using Django with Taggit(Selectize) and I would like to give users the option to click on "suggestion-tags" and that they appear in the input field. I wrote some JS its working in the console but not in the template. No tags appear in the input field but the given tags are saved and when the user reloads the page the tags are displayed in the Input field.

```js
$('.tags_select a').click(function() {
  var valueText = $(this).text();
  var input = $('#id_I_want');
  oldInput = input.val();
  $('#id_I_want').val(oldInput + " " + valueText);
  newInput = input.val();
  $(input).text(newInput);
  return false;
});
```

```html
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<p class="formItems"> {{ SetForm.I_want|add_class:"" }}</p>
<div class="tags_select">
  <span>Tags</span>
  <a href="#">Fun</a>
  <a href="#">Lala</a>
  <a href="#">Airline</a>
</div>
```

I also tried to do an ajax call but same thing saved and displayed in the console but not shown in template when clicked. It is a Django form. I think that is the problem or it has something to to with Taggit.

Does anybody know how I can make the tags appear immediately when they are clicked? [image]

EDIT: 
so to make clear what i am trying to do: If a User clicks on one of these "Trending Tags" it should appear in the input field where the other (already selected) Tags are.

SOLUTION:
So thanks to @Håken Lid I found this Solution for Selectize with Taggit:

```
 $('.tags_select a').click(function() {
  var selectize = $("#id_I_want_to_see")[0].selectize;
  value = $(this).text();
  selectize.createItem(value)
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. I assume that the jquery code is the problem, but I don't understand what the expected behaviour is. [mcve]

Comment: I hope that clears the issue

Comment: Do you use some special widget library to make the input field look like that? With a regular `input` field, the javascript code should work.

Comment: Yes i use Django Taggit with Selectize. I tested the jQuery Code myself to make sure it worked and it did the problem here is to get the thing to run with Taggit and Selectize. I would like to have a Tag input field like StackOverflow when you ask a question....

Comment: The problem is caused by Selectize. To get the fancy input, it hides the actual input element, and shows a div instead. Div can have child elements with styling, unlike input. The problem is that there's no two way binding. So even if you update the hidden input, the selectize-input does not reflect those changes.

Comment: You might find a solution here. https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: yeah i played a little with `this.parent().find("input")/next("input)` and was able to fill the words into he field but they had no styling and were hidden behind the other tags. Maybe I find a trick at some point. Thanks anyway. Will check out that link :)

Comment: @Håken Lid  if you want you can write an answer (so i can select it) I found a solution for the problem in the link you posted. Thanks a ton I already wanted to give up, didnt think it would be that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by Selectize. To get the fancy input, it hides the actual input element, and shows a div instead. `Div` can have child elements with styling, unlike `input`. The problem is that there's no two way binding. So even if you update the hidden input, the selectize-input does not reflect those changes.

You should be able to find a solution to how you can update the value in a selectize-input by refering to the selectize api docs: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

```
$('.tags_select a').click(function() {
  var selectize = $("#id_I_want_to_see")[0].selectize;
  value = $(this).text();
  selectize.createItem(value)
});
```